# Spring JPA Query getResultList returning data as application/json

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have a web application that uses Spring JPA and I have the following function that works fine in my integration test

```
public List<PermissionQueryDTO> findByCompanyAndEventType(int companyId, int eventTypeId) {
    Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(FIND_BY_COMPANY_AND_EVENT_TYPE_QUERY, "PermissionQueryMapping");
    query.setParameter("companyId", companyId);
    query.setParameter("eventTypeId", eventTypeId);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

How ever when run in my Web App I get this error message:

```
Could not locate appropriate constructor on class : a.b.c.PermissionQueryDTO] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@346a9eea]
```

Anyone know why I'm getting this error

Comment: Why are you using StringHttpMessageConverter? Try MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the Result Set Mapping didn't have a type specified. I had to change this:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name="PermissionQueryMapping",
    classes={
        @ConstructorResult(
            targetClass=PermissionQueryDTO.class,
            columns={
                @ColumnResult(name="prop_id"),
                @ColumnResult(name="prop_description"s),
                @ColumnResult(name="prop_code"),
                @ColumnResult(name="prop_pt_id"),
                @ColumnResult(name="permissionId"),
                @ColumnResult(name="uplineStationPermissionLevel"),
                @ColumnResult(name="previousStationPermissionLevel"),
                @ColumnResult(name="eventStationPermissionLevel"),
                @ColumnResult(name="nextStationPermissionLevel",
                @ColumnResult(name="downlineStationPermissionLevel"),
            }
        )
    } 
)
```

To this:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name="PermissionQueryMapping",
    classes={
        @ConstructorResult(
            targetClass=PermissionQueryDTO.class,
            columns={
                @ColumnResult(name="prop_id", type=Integer.class),
                @ColumnResult(name="prop_description", type=String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name="prop_code", type=String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name="prop_pt_id", type=Integer.class),
                @ColumnResult(name="permissionId", type=Integer.class),
                @ColumnResult(name="uplineStationPermissionLevel", type=Integer.class),
                @ColumnResult(name="previousStationPermissionLevel", type=Integer.class),
                @ColumnResult(name="eventStationPermissionLevel", type=Integer.class),
                @ColumnResult(name="nextStationPermissionLevel", type=Integer.class),
                @ColumnResult(name="downlineStationPermissionLevel", type=Integer.class),
            }
        )
    } 
)
```